# Xamarin iOS MEF issue

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.ios, mef

In my project based on Xamarin Forms, I'm trying to use MEF for getting classes from referenced assemblies. All my code in Portable library. Android project working fine, but on runnig iOS project on such code:

```
public class AssemblyLoaderStatic
{
    public AssemblyLoaderStatic(Assembly assembly)
    {
        AssemblyCatalog assemblyCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(assembly);
        Container = new CompositionContainer(assemblyCatalog);
    }
    public CompositionContainer Container { get; set; }
}
```

on line `AssemblyCatalog assemblyCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(assembly);` it's raising exception:

> System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AssemblyCatalog:.ctor (System.Reflection.Assembly): method body is empty.

It seams that ctor is not implemented on ios mono?
Has anyone working code? Any workaround?